# Java struts application deployed but refuses to start

Tags: java, tomcat, struts2

I have built the war archieve for a struts application and deployed but sometimes it refuses to start. when i througly checked it, i found that tomcat refuses to start the application if there is no internet connection even though its just a hello world application with no web service being used. On closer examination I found that the error is thrown while parsing struts.xml file when there is no internet connection. Seems as though the DTD is being checked to parse it and in absence of internet connection its not possible to fetch DTD and auto extracting and starting of the war archieve file fails.

How can this problem be avoided so as to work with no internet connection. I use netbeans and am a novice.

Comment: Try add new **Schema Location** in **XML Catalog** of Preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the DTD, putting it on your local host and pointing to the local DTD in your doctype declaration.

Comment: that i know but i don't find that a good option. may be there could be some method of ignoring that process or exception.